# Aurelia binding between component and sub-component not reflecting changes

Tags: aurelia

I have a text input in both main view and in a custom component. I want the text of them to be in sync (more specifically, from main -> sub component).

Here is what I've got:

**`app.html`**

```
<template>
  <require from="my-component"></require>
  Parent App Text: <input type="text" value.bind="mainAppText" />
  <br />
  <my-component myComponentText.bind="mainAppText"></my-component>
</template>
```

**`app.js`**

```
export class App {
  mainAppText;
}
```

**`my-component.html`**

```
<template>
  My Component Text: <input type="text" value.bind="myComponentText" />
</template>
```

**`my-component.js`**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyComponent {
  @bindable myComponentText;
}
```

But `myComponentText` won't update. What am I missing?

**Plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/infT53A3Y2aGbN9CR7B5?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check your code here (do not use such naming for properties): http://plnkr.co/edit/qPkDqnLKa0I9nzJ0wTsc?p=preview

```
<my-component text.bind="mainAppText"></my-component>
```

and

```
@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent {
  @bindable
  text = '(default)';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I believe this is because camel/pascal-casing violates HTML5 attributes naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<my-component myComponentText.two-way="mainAppText"></my-component>
```

I'm not sure if it's the rule but I made the experience that 'bind' only works two-way on standard attributes.

Comment: Didn't work. I've updated the plunker adding the sub-component with both `bind` and `two-way` binding approaches.

Comment: <my-component my-component-text.two-way="mainAppText"></my-component>